# Dockerizing a Windows Service Docker for Windows

Tags: windows-services, docker-for-windows

I have a existing Windows Service which I want to move to docker container in windows. I'm new to this. If somebody can help me how to create docker image to move windows service into docker, it would be helpful.

Comment: Convert Windows Service into Console APP. And using dotnet-framework, create docker image for the project and respectively container.

Answer (score 5):

First, download [wait-service](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/live/windows-server-container-tools/Wait-Service/Wait-Service.ps1) script 
You need to write dockerfile like this

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR /
COPY Wait-Service.ps1 service.exe ./
RUN install_you_service
CMD c:\Wait-Service.ps1 -ServiceName 'service' -AllowServiceRestart
```

then open powershel and folder with you dockerfile and run

```
docker build .
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting an existing windows servie to run in a docker container is fairly easy.  You will need to get the [installutil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool) mentioned in this script before it will work.  It is part of the .NET framework. The last 9 lines of code here are not needed if your service doesn't log to the Event Viewer.

```
# escape=\

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1709

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

COPY ["MyWindowsServiceName/bin/Release/", "/Service/"]

WORKDIR "C:/Service/"

RUN "C:/Service/InstallUtil.exe" /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack MyWindowsServiceName.exe; \
    Set-Service -Name "\"MyWindowsServiceName\"" -StartupType Automatic; \
    Set-ItemProperty "\"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyWindowsServiceName\"" -Name AllowRemoteConnection -Value 1

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell"]
CMD Start-Service \""MyWindowsServiceName\""; \
    Get-EventLog -LogName System -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) | Format-List ;\
    $idx = (get-eventlog -LogName System -Newest 1).Index; \
    while ($true) \
    {; \
    start-sleep -Seconds 1; \
    $idx2  = (Get-EventLog -LogName System -newest 1).index; \
    get-eventlog -logname system -newest ($idx2 - $idx) |  sort index | Format-List; \
    $idx = $idx2; \
    }
```

**NOTE**: The name of a windows service may be different to its executable name.  That is, 'MyWindowsServiceName.exe' could have a service name of 'My Windows Service Name' or 'Fred', you need to know both.