# Install Windows service in Docker container

Tags: docker, windows-services, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

When I try to install an app as a service in my `dockerfile` I get an error that indicates that `installutil.exe` is showing the username dialog when installing the service. Initially I wanted to use an account on the host's domain, but it seems Docker for Windows doesn't support the host network setting that is available on linux.

To get around this I am creating an admin user first and then calling installutil with the username and password parameters. This gives the error

> The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is
>   invalid for the account name specified.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework
SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]

RUN New-LocalUser -Name "testuser" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Stackoverflow1234!" -Force) -FullName "Test.User" -Description "LocalAdministrator"
RUN Add-LocalGroupMember -Group administrators -Member  adapteruser -Verbose

RUN New-Item -Path "C:/dev" -ItemType directory

WORKDIR /dev

COPY ".\dev" "C:\dev"

RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/InstallUtil.exe" /username=testuser /password=Stackoverflow1234! /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack myapp.exe
```

I've also tried:

```
RUN net user /add testuser Stackoverflow1234!
RUN net localgroup administrators testuser /add
RUN net user
```

I have reviewed this similar question already:
[Dockerizing a Windows Service Docker for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741364/dockerizing-a-windows-service-docker-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

To use the new user I had to add ".\" to the username (for local machine):

```
RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/InstallUtil.exe" /username=.\testuser /password=Stackoverflow1234! /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack myapp.exe
```